# When to use Integer.parseint

Tags: java, numbers

Why is Integer.parseint() used when we have type casting?

Maybe another way to ask this question would be:

When should Integer.parseint() be used over type casting?

Comment: Your new question has nothing to do with the original one... Please decide what you want to ask for before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type casting is used to make object of one type assign to other without altering or parsing the contents of the object. While parseInt method parses the String values and converts it to integer value i.e. converts String value to integer.

Type casting has nothing to do with contents of the object. It is only used for assigning reference type of one type to another.
Eg : `Object obj = new String(""); String string = (String) obj;`

Comment: This is true, but it is worth nothing that type casts for primitive types typically *do* entail value conversion.

Answer (score -2):

```
// System.out.println(foos);
int foo = Integer.parseInt("45");

foo+= 3;
System.out.println(foo);
int zoo = Integer.parseInt("4576876");
System.out.println(zoo);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).